# How can I sort the order of status messages?

Tags: 7, users

I add my own validations to forms, for example the user registration. The errors I set with [form_set_error](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error) are added below the drupal generated errors. 
I would like to show them in the same order of my form fields on the page.

I thought I can use [theme_status_messages](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7)($variables). When I do a dpm($variables) on a from with status messages it just shows an empty array.

Comment: As `theme_status_messages()` is used from Drupal, and the messages are shown, the function clearly works. How are you overriding that theme function?

Comment: I add this to my bartik/template.php: function bartik_status_messages(&$variables) {
 var_dump($variables);
}. It shows "array(1) { ["display"]=> NULL }" and the status message isn't shown. If I remove it it shows the messages from the previous page. Found this related link http://drupal.org/node/1049648 but still can't solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$variables['display']`, passed to the theme function is optional, and its purpose is only to limit the type of messages being shown; for example, if its value is "error," only the error messages should be shown. The list of messages is returned from [drupal_get_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7), which should be called as `drupal_get_messages($variables['display'])`.

To answer to your comment, you can avoid duplicating all the code used by `theme_status_messages()` if you follow these steps:

- obtain the array of messages from `drupal_get_messages()`
- sort the obtained array of messages
- use the array to set the content of `$_SESSION['messages']`, which is the session variable used to contain all the messages set from the modules
- call `theme_status_messages()`, passing the same argument passed to your theme function (not the array obtained from `drupal_get_messages()`)

This method seems half of a hack, to me. What happens if Drupal would change how the list of messages are saved? It could be that future Drupal versions will not use a session variable for this purpose.
It also take the assumption that other modules didn't override the theme function, but it would be easy in the implementation of `hook_theme_registry_alter()` to save the previously defined theme function, and call that function instead of assuming that function is `theme_status_messages()`.

Comment: thank you. I can now get the array of status messages and display them. I was hoping I can just sort the array and return it to be rendered by drupal's default status message function.  Looks like I have to copy all the code from http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7 to display the HTML myself.

Comment: I expanded my answer to reply to your comment.