# Disabling update notifications

Tags: 7, updating, notifications

I'm trying to remove the update notifications from the Drupal backend. I tried with [Update notifications disable](http://drupal.org/project/update_notifications_disable) module but it breaks the "module" part of the backend. I can disable the Update manager module but i don't like this solution. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove them for a less cluttered back end, that perhaps doesn't worry non-technical admin users you could maybe CSS them out?

Comment: Yes, it's a solution but it will remove other error messages too.

Comment: I guess you're right. I assumed there would be a specific class you could target, but there isn't.

You could try and theme it out with this this http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7

but there might be a better way via a hook...

Comment: and maybe a relevant comment on this thread http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14840/how-can-i-sort-the-order-of-status-messages