# How can I disable theme update notifications?

Tags: 7

How can I disable Drupal update notifications for certain themes?

I am using the Drupal Bootstrap 7.x-3.0 Theme which is not the latest version. That is why Drupal sends out a email Update notifications and shows a update warning. I don’t want to miss any module updates, thus I would  like to keep update notification enabled. However I don’t want receive theme update message all time.I didn’t know that this is such difficult approach.

I was looking for a easy solution e.g. theme .info settings or on/off option in Drupals settings.php.

Comment: I would look at this answer, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/25044/247

Comment: I take the OP doesn't want to simply hide them, but to avoid Drupal checks for updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Update Status Advanced Settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/update_advanced) enables you to disable any project, including themes, that you don't want to be alerted about updates for.

> Extends the administrative interface for Drupal core's "Update status" module (added to core in 6.x).
>
> Users of the 5.x Update status contrib module will probably want to use this once they upgrade to 6.x, since some of the functionality in the contrib version was deemed too complicated to include in core. In particular, the per-project settings to ignore certain projects or even specific releases, is absent in the core version of the module. The "Update status advanced settings" module restores these settings, and might eventually provide additional functionality for the core "Update status" module.

Comment: Insteaf of using a additional module I was looking for a easy solution e.g. theme .info settings or on/off option in Drupals settings.php.

Comment: @howdytom No, there isn't a Drupal core settings for that, and not for themes.

Comment: @howdytom, this is the simplest solution I know of: installation and configuration of the module. It'd be nice to not need a module for such a problem, but that's they way it goes sometimes.